# How to convert text file from lower-case to upper case and save as new file

Tags: linux, command-line

Please would someone be able to explain how I can convert all the lower case characters in a text file to upper case and then save it as a new file? My file is called NewFile.txt and contains 500 lines of random characters.

Comment: Similar: [How to convert UTF-8 txt files to all uppercase in bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/84942)

Answer (score 25):

In the POSIX toolchest, there's:

```
<input.txt tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' >output.txt
```

However note that [with the GNU implementation, that only works for single-byte characters](/q/228558); so in locales using the UTF-8 charset for instance, only on abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz letters without diacritics.

```
<input.txt awk '{print toupper($0)}' >output.txt
```

is also POSIX and works OK with the GNU implementation of `awk`.

```
<input.txt dd conv=ucase >output.txt
```

is also POSIX but not many implementations will transliterate non-ASCII characters.

```
<input.txt sed 's/.*/\U&/g' > output.txt
```

Works in GNU `sed`, but GNU `sed` only (that `\U` is not standard).

With `perl`:

```
<input.txt perl -Mopen=locale -pe '$_=uc' >output.txt
```

That one doesn't use the locale's `toupper` rules, so may work better on words like *oﬃce* (converting that one `ﬃ` character to the three character `FFI`¹).

`uconv`, from the ICU project should be pretty good at handling all sorts of international corner cases, and assuming input / output encoded in UTF-8 (or whatever `uconv --default-code` returns; though see the `-f`/`--from-code` and `-t`/`--to-code` options to specify different input and output encodings):

```
<input.txt uconv -x upper >output.txt
```

Within the `vim` editor, if on the first character of the file (`gg` to get there), enter `gUG` to convert all to uppercase til the end of the file. Then `:saveas output.txt` to save to output file.

Or with any `ex` or `vi` implementation (though not all will handle non-ASCII characters): `:%s/.*/\U&/` (and `:w output.txt` to write the edited file to `output.txt` and `:q!` to quit without saving the now modified input file).

With the `zsh` shell:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
mapfile[output.txt]=${(U)mapfile[input.txt]}
# or (csh-style):
mapfile[output.txt]=$mapfile[input.txt]:u
```

To convert from upper to lower case instead, in case that's not already obvious:

- `tr`: swap `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]`
- `awk`: change `toupper` to `tolower`
- `dd`: change `ucase` to `lcase`
- GNU `sed` / `ex` / `vi`: change `\U` to `\L`
- `perl`: change `uc` to `lc`.
- `uconv`: change `upper` to `lower`
- `vim`: change `gUG` to `guG` (that's the trick one).
- `zsh`: change `(U)` to `(L)`, `:u` to `:l`.

---

<sup>¹ the C / POSIX `toupper()` / `towupper()` API only converts one character to another one at a time, so is limited in how it can change the case of text. See https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/posix.html#case-mappings about that and more.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A bash one(ish) liner using only builtins...

```
f="$(< infile.txt)" ; printf "%s" "${f^^}" > outfile.txt ; unset f
```

We fill temporary variable `f` with the content of `infile.txt`.

Then we print `f` to STDOUT while using bash variable trickery to uppercase it (`${f^^}`) and redirect STDOUT to `outfile.txt`.

*Caveat: Probably going to play up if the "randomness" deviates from Latin and printable characters.  Also drops any trailing newlines.*

Per comments, this is probably better (more efficient, no newline dropping):

```
readarray f < infile.txt ; printf %s "${f[@]^^}" > outfile.txt ; unset f
```

Comment: Also note that it removes all the trailing newline characters (including the one delimiting the last line if non empty), so would in effect make `outfile.txt` non-text. It also removes NUL characters (though those are not meant to occur in txt files)

Comment: Using `IFS= read -rd '' f < infile.txt` would probably be better (avoids the fork, though may still be inefficient as `read` reads by small chunks, and the trimming of newlines; would stop at the first NUL though).

Comment: Another option would be `readarray  f < infile.txt; printf %s "${f[@]^^}"` (also assuming no NUL in the input, but likely more efficient than `read` or `$(<file)`).

Comment: Huh, somehow I never noticed that `$( )` dropped trailing newlines. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: FWIW, `bash`'s `${var^^}` should be OK for characters in non-Latin scripts as long as the locale defines the rules for converting them. It should call the libc's `towupper()` on each successfully decoded character like zsh's `$var:u`

Comment: @bxm, you wouldn't notice if you print the result out using `echo`, since it adds a newline... Dropping the trailing newlines is really useful if you embed a command substitution within some string, like `echo "$(date): something happened`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the command line using GNU `sed` (what you are most likely using on your Linux system):

```
sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g' filename >newfilename
```

Explanation:

`sed` is a program you can use to process a stream of strings into something else using regular expressions. It accepts input from standard input or from a file, and writes to standard output.

Now to break down the regular expression used:

to do a substitution, you use the syntax `s/<expression>/<new_expression>/g`. You use one expression to find the matching text you want to substitute and the other to dictate how to replace. The regular expression we used to find the match was `([a-z])` (ignoring the backslashes which escape the parentheses). This regular expression looks for any lower case character; surrounding the expression with parentheses lets us save the character for future reference.

Then, for the substitution, we use `\U\1`, where `\U` converts to upper case ("U" for upper), and `\1` is the character we saved by surrounding the regex with parentheses

---

Further Reading:

- [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions). These are the parentheses we used to save the match for future reference and referred to it again with `\1`
- [Upper/Lower case conversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Locale-Considerations.html#Upper_002fLower-case-conversion). Here you will find a detailed description of `\U`, as well as other operators you can use for conversion

Comment: More efficient to do the whole line at once: `sed 's/.*/\U&/' file`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, note that it would only change the first sequence of characters on each line. Adding the `g` flag (as in my answer) would help for bogus text files that contain spurious bytes not forming part of valid characters. Also (re your edit), how do you determine which is the most common sed implementation on Linux. With 99.9% of Linux-based systems running some embedded OS or Android, I doubt a large portion would include GNU `sed` (if any `sed`), though I'll agree the OP's one will likely not be one of those.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are correct on both accounts. In my comment, I was echoing the GNU sed manual without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

A perl [one-liners](https://catonmat.net/introduction-to-perl-one-liners) are a fun way of doing this.

```
perl -ne 'print uc' NewFile.txt > output.txt
```

The `-n` assigns each line to `$_` which is passed as a default argument to `uc` (uppercase) and is executed with `-e`.  Or you could use

```
perl -pe '$_ = uc' NewFile.txt > output.txt
```

where the `-p` is the same as `-n`, but adds an implicit `print $_` to the end of the `-e` command.

A big motto in Perl is There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

Comment: Note that `perl -pe '$_=uc'` (though with `-Mopen=locale` so as to work with text in the user's format instead of ASCII) was already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas The reason I missed your perl answer was that you started out with `tr` and `awk` and only half way down, you mentioned `perl` which just looked like more code while I was skimming responses.  I'd suggest that when you consider different languages in your answer that you **bold** them or use a markdown header to organize your response for us tl;dr types ;)

Answer (score 0):

The suggested sed-oneliners (@Stéphane Chazelas, @Kusalananda) all use the "s"-subcommand, which is not the best tool for the job. Changing one (set of) character(s) to another is easier and better done with "y":

```
sed 'y/abcde/ABCDE/' infile > outfile
```

will translate any occurrence of the first character in the first string to the first character in the second string, any occurrence of the second character in the first string to the second character in the second string and so on. Replace in the above the "abcde"-strings with whatever "character translation table" you want and you can convert files with any character set/encoding sed is able to handle.

Comment: You can't change `ß` to `SS` or `ﬃ` to `FFI` with that though (the `s` command with `\U` in GNU `sed` or `vim`, contrary to that of `perl` doesn't either though). Doing it for the ~2000 lower case characters in Unicode would end up in a several kilobyte large  command line. Note that `sed`'s `y` command works like `tr`'s except it doesn't support ranges. `tr abcde ABCDE` which would be the same can be written `tr a-e A-E`.